# How to filter month and year in vb 2010 / access

Tags: vb.net, date, filter

How do I filter month and year from an Access database with a datetime column. The format used in the database is "General Date", an example of which is `1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM`.

In hoping do this, I have a DateTimePicker which is set to a custom format `yyyy/MMM (2015/Jan)`. I have thought of converting the `yyyy/MMM` to `general date` format but I am worried that it will mess up the filtering somewhat.

The results will be displayed in a DataGridView.

Comment: all those formats are simply how the dates are displayed to humans.  The DateTime vars themselves have no format

Comment: I tried filtering the datetime by using `source1.Filter = [att_date] = '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' "` but it gives me a blank datagridview.

Comment: a) are there records for that date? b) what is the column data type for `att_date` c) why do you convert a perfectly good DateTime type to string by enclosing it in ticks?

Comment: a) I am trying to filter it by month, so when I choose for example 2015/Jan there should be 1 record there.
b)Date/Time
c)Noob mistake, I think hehe but now I removed the ticks, and its giving me a missing operand error.